# content of htaccess slows down Joomla Website

Tags: .htaccess, joomla, web

I am trying to remove "index.php" from the url of my website. However it worked with my secondary website but not with my primary. 
After renaming htaccess.txt to .htaccess i entered following code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
```

After activating URL-Rewrite in the Joomla-Backend the "index.php" is gone but the sites takes about 20 seconds to load. Clearing the .htaccess makes the site load properly again (about 1 second) but the "index.php" is obviously there again.

It is really important for me to change the URL and maybe someone can help me out :)

Answer (score 1):

Which version of Joomla you are using. If it is 3.x series then there is no need to write your customized code for URL rewriting since it is already present in htaccess. please check for the duplication of code or try to replace with original Joomla htaccess.

Comment: I am using the latest joomla version. After using the original htaccess and activating URL-Rewrite in the Joomla Backend the site is extremely slow again. I restored to my backup and the site was loading normally again but URL-Rewrite does obviously not work. Any ideas??